# Layer adds and removes itself within a second in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I am trying to create a layer with a feature class and adding to arcmap. using below code.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

inputLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# get the map document
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

# get the data frame
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inputFCpath, layerpathName)

# create a new layer
newlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layerpathName)

# add the layer to the map at the bottom of the TOC in data frame 0
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, newlayer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

it creates a layer adds in TOC and removes itself immediately from TOC.

why TOC not holding this Layer ?

Comment: Where are you defining inputFCpath, and layerpathName variables?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug which was supposedly fixed at 10.0 SP1. However, there's a [geonet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/message/133242) in which several users still report issues at SP1.

The [bug report](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDUyNzQx) offers a few alternate solutions you could try with your current ArcGIS version.